# Image count is zero

Tags: python, tensorflow-lite, google-codelab

I am trying to create image classification model using tensorflow lite for android app here: `https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification` However,
I am using my local directory.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

import pathlib
data_dir = pathlib.Path('C:/Users/aalroumi/Documents/MLKIT/V')

image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.JPEG')))
print(image_count)
```

and here is an image of the output:

![][1]

and this is the image of my local directory:

So why am I getting image size is zero?

Am I missing something? I did everything right.

Because I am trying to `files.download('model.tflite')`

Image size is zero error:

Thank you

Comment: Your glob pattern has a slash in it, implying the images should be in subdirectories, but it appears that they are not. Could that be it?

Comment: That is actually true. It shows the number of images but again when I am loading, why does it show image size is zero? if you see I edit my reply and it shows the error in the image. Thank you for the help though for the previous enquiry.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Comment: first you should check in documentation `from_folder` - maybe it loads only `.jpg` but you have `.JPEG`. OR maybe it needs special package with images and labels.

Comment: based on source code `from_folder(data_dir)` needs images in subfolders which are used as labels - `data_dir/label1/*.jpeg`, etc, `data_dir/label2/*.jpeg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have images directly in `data_dir` so you should use `*.JPEG` to get them in `glob()`

---

But `from_folder(data_dir)` expects images in subfolders which names will be used as `labels` for images.

ie.

```
data_dir/cat/small_cat.JPEG
data_dir/cat/big_cat.JPEG
# ...
data_dir/dog/white_dog.JPEG
data_dir/dog/black_dog.JPEG
```

but you don't have subfolders so it can't find images in subfolders.
It doesn't count images directly in `data_dir`